# Переменная больше одного значения и меньше другого

Tags: javascript

доброго всем!
Хочу if реализовать в одной строке
переменная больше одного значения и меньше другого, примерно так:

> if ( Xday > 1 [но] < 5)

Извините, но я с JS на вы...
Как такое реализовать?
Или двумя условиями мерить?

Comment: А вы, простите, с каким языком программирования в хороших отношениях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( Xday > 1 && Xday < 5){

}
```

&& - логическое И.
Логического "но" не предусмотрено.

Можете еще написать так:

```
function between(x,a,b){
  "use strict";
  return (x>a and x<b);
}
```

использование:

```
between(x,1,5);
```

можно попытаться замутить x.between(1,5), но для этого надо либо каждый раз создавать объект x, либо добавлять свойства встроенным объектам, что очень-очень нехорошо, пока вы на вы с js:)